# Google Domain Rejects Use of onClick Call to a Function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a simple function that I want to call when the user clicks a button on a modal dialog box. Testing this out in my personal gmail email it works exactly as expected. However, when using my work domain (e.g. email@work.com, where 'work' is my work domain) I get the console error "uncaught".

It does not give any specific details and just doesn't work. The dialog box stays open with the function not being ran. It will close just fine if I click that button with the follow script, but when submit is hit it refuses to call the outside function. Any idea why this would only be happening on this particular domain? Is there a setting that can be changed somewhere? Here is the code:

```
//This function creates the html table that is displayed in the modal dialog box.
    function makeTableHTML() {
      //var officeSelection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main_gen').getRange(2, 1).getValue();
      var PartnerEmailList = ['test','test2','test3'];
      var result = "<table border=0>";
      result += "<tr><td style=\"text-align:center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name =" + PartnerEmailList[0] + " value =" + PartnerEmailList[0] + " checked></input></td>";
      result += "<td style=\"vertical-align:text-middle\">" + PartnerEmailList[0] + "</td></tr>";
      for(var i=1; i<PartnerEmailList.length; i++) {
        result += "<tr><td style=\"text-align:center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" unchecked></input></td>";
        result += "<td style=\"vertical-align:text-middle\">" + PartnerEmailList[i] + "</td></tr>";
      }
      result += "</table>";
      //result += "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"action\" onclick=\"form_data()\">";
      //result += "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Close\" onclick=\"google.script.host.close()\">";

  const htmlTest = `
  ${result}
  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="action" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => google.script.host.close()).form_data()">
  <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()">
  `
  return htmlTest;
}

function DisplayOptions(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = makeTableHTML();
  var bccSend = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main_gen').getRange(2,2).getValue();
   if(bccSend === ''){
    //Call the HTML file and set the width and height
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(result)
      .setWidth(450)
      .setHeight(300);

  //Display the dialog
  var dialog = ui.showModalDialog(html, "Select the intended recipients of this briefing.");
  } 
}

function form_data(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Send Aborted.');
}
```

Comment: I find it a lot easier to use Utilities.formatString() where building  dialogs like that.

Comment: I tried your code with both Gmail and G Suite accounts and it worked fine. I would contact [G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) in your case.